# How To SELECT Category For Each Post Id In PHP Function

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, function

I have the following code that extracts data out of my Wordpress database. I would like to also add the category to each line of information.

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS focuskw,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_title' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS title,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS metadesc,
$wpdb->posts.ID, $wpdb->posts.post_type FROM `$wpdb->posts`
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_meta-robots-noindex' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)is null
AND ($wpdb->posts.post_type = 'page' OR $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'post') 
");

header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    echo "</br>{$post->ID},{$post->post_type},{$permalink},{$post->focuskw}";
}
```

I understand that in the following part, I should add my code:

```
global $wpdb;
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("
SELECT (SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_focuskw' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS focuskw,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_title' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS title,
(SELECT `meta_value` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `meta_key` = '_yoast_wpseo_metadesc' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS metadesc,
```

So, adding to the last line above, I was trying to add something like:

```
(SELECT `wp_term_taxonomy` FROM `$wpdb->postmeta` WHERE `taxonomy` = 'category' AND post_id = $wpdb->posts.ID)  AS category,
```

Basically, I get that I need to pull from MySQL, but I'm not sure of how to format the PHP code and which path to use. I did some research on the 'get_the_category' option, but am unsure of how to implement it into this code.

How can I have this code return the post categories too? Any positive input or direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: I think this query allows some room for improvement :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I actually needed to add the code to the bottom. I used the 'get_the-category' function:

```
header('Content-type:text/plain');
foreach($posts as $post) {
    $category = get_the_category($post->ID);
        $postcat = $category[0]->cat_name;
    $permalink = get_permalink($post->ID);
    echo "</br>{$post->ID},{$post->post_type},{$permalink},{$postcat},{$post->focuskw}";
}
```

Hope this helps anyone trying to list categories and posts in a PHP script.